# List all kinds in Google datastore except reserved one (java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In Appengine (java), I'm able to list all the entities of my datastore using this code to delete them later. The problem is that I get lots of `The kind "__XXX_Kind__" is reserved.` in the logs, so I'd like a way to retrieve all the entities under kinds which are not reserved.

Is this possible ?

```
do {
    FetchOptions options = FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(100);
    if(cursor != null) {
        options.startCursor(cursor);
    }
    QueryResultList<Entity> results = pq.asQueryResultList(options);
    if(results.size() > 0) {
        for (Entity result : results) {
            try {
                datastore.delete(result.getKey());   
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.warning(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        cursor = results.getCursor();
    } else {
        cursor = null;
    }
} while(cursor != null);
```

Comment: Do you see these kinds only with the local devserver or also when deployed on GAE?

Comment: Only when deployed actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get all Kinds from the Metadata. Using GQL, you can run the below query to list all Kinds:

```
SELECT __key__ FROM __kind__ ORDER BY __key__
```

This will return all Kinds, including any System Kinds; kinds start with double underscores (e.g. `__Stat_Kind__`).

While iterating over the results of the above query, just exclude the System Kinds and then run your delete for each kind to do the cleanup.

Depending on the API you are using, if it does not support GQL, use the equivalent Query Builder and run it.

Take a look at this [AppEngine Datastore documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/metadataqueries#Java_Kind_queries.)

Comment: That's what I ended up with too but I thought there would be some "cleaner" way to do it. Anyway, will mark your answer as solution since it's the only one I got :)